# How to get days in a week from today in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get the days of a week in reference to their date.
Ex.: 14th October is a Wednesday.
I am creating a collection view cell and displaying the date as follows.
[image]

In the 14th cell it would display Wednesday, but how to get the next day as Thursday, then Friday...and so on.

I have got todays date and which day it is as follows,

```
day = [components day];
week = [components month];
year = [components year];
weekday = [components weekday];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.%ld.%ld", (long)day, (long)week, (long)year];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date]; // get today date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];// here convert date in
NSLog(@"Today formatted date is %@",convertedDateString);
```

And i have found this method online, which returns the days in string when you pass the integer, but i am having trouble in this too, not understanding which integer to pass every time so I get different strings.

```
static inline NSString *stringFromWeekday(int weekday){
static NSString *strings[] = {
    @"Sunday",
    @"Monday",
    @"Tuesday",
    @"Wednesday",
    @"Thursday",
    @"Friday",
    @"Saturday",
};

return strings[weekday];
```

}

Comment: So you aren't using different `NSDate` objects for each cell / button / whatever display? You should be...

Comment: @Wain, yes i was not using different `NSDate` objects for each collection view cell earlier, Now i have changed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already got everything in place. You should be getting the correct day name in the `convertedDateString` string. You just have to add 24 hours to your `todayDate` object and use the `dateformatter` again to get the next day.

```
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date]; // get today date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];// here convert date in
```

You can get the next day like this.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalenderUnit | NSYearCalenderUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
[dateComponents setDay:dateComponents.day+1];
NSDate *nextDay = [dateComponents date];
// Get the day by following same approach in the top
```

Comment: use `NSDateComponents` to add a day, you don't know there are always 24 hours in a day...

Comment: the (24*60*60) works and the method `setDate` shows no known interface found. But i have got the days of week.

Comment: Using 24*60*60 won't create problem in your case. Its setDay btw, not setDate.

Comment: @RamarajT nextDay gives me a null value , any reason ?

Comment: got it i had to set the calender before getting the date

Comment: Yes, do  [dateComponents setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]]; before setting the day.

Answer (score 0):

You will get days in a week from today using below code.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [weekdayComponents day];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```